# Angular JS Button ng-click doesn't call method

Tags: angularjs, button, angular-fullstack

for now I read a lot of post for this problem, but none seems to have a solution.

In my angular app I created a new route with angular-fullstack:route

So here are my controller, template and config file:

controller:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  class AnmeldungCtrl {

    constructor($http, $window, $uibModal, $state) {

    }

    searchUser(searchString) {
      console.log("search Method");
      if (searchString.isNaN()) {
        this.state = "search";
        console.log("search");
        //TODO Search for name
      }
      else if (searchString >= 1000000) {
        this.state = "anmeldung";
        console.log("anmeldung");
        //TODO Search for bar code
      }
      else {
        this.state = "edit";
        console.log("edit");
        //TODO Search for Participant
      }
    }
  }

  angular.module('schwimmfestivalApp').controller('AnmeldungCtrl', AnmeldungCtrl);
})();
```

template:

```
<div>

  <input type="text" ng-model="query" >

  <button ng-click="ctrl.searchUser(query)">Search</button>
  {{query}}
</div>
```

config file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('schwimmfestivalApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('anmeldung', {
        url: '/anmeldung',
        templateUrl: 'app/anmeldung/anmeldung.html',
        controller: 'AnmeldungCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
      });
  });
```

As I mention in my heading for some reason the method at the controller doesn't get called. And I have no idea why.

At my other routes it does work.

I hope you can give me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide some Plunk or jsfiddel for better understanding.

Comment: `ctrl.searchUser = function (searchString) {...}`

Comment: is the controller file included in your project?

Comment: yes it is <script src="app/anmeldung/anmeldung.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/anmeldung/anmeldung.js"></script>

Comment: @Viplock I'm sorry but I never get fiddles work with angular ... :(

Comment: @dominic can you check, is there any error on console ?

Comment: @Viplock no the console stays blank. That is the biggest problem at this point. If there where an error I could look up for this. I'm wondering because in different controllers in this app this setup does work.

Comment: @dominic i created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gUy2Gj9eDPinFKfEWOSK?p=preview) based on your provided code and it works normally.

Comment: Okay I got it to work. It was a fault at my point (as expected). A colleague of mine created a cnontroller in an other path with the same identifire ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got it to work. It was a fault at my point (as expected). A colleague of mine created a cnontroller in an other path with the same identifier.

So angular doesn't throw an error if something like this happened. Because the second controller was in a lower path it came at the include after the original controller.

Thanks to @MMhunter who put a console output at the constructor. This wasn't printed in my dev environment. So I started to search why, and found the second controller.

Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try using just searchUser(query) it might work because controller is already added no need to call the function using controller

Comment: this doesn't work there is no output to my browser console

Comment: its not the solution.